# Option to activate error screen on XCODE

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Its been a day since i have been working on XCODE on my mac.
Till yesterday , the errors were getting displayed properly in the output  editor below.
I am not sure what settings i have changed, the errors and warnings  are nt getting displayed though the build  failed.
Though there are errors in my code,they are nt getting displayed.

Please advise me what has to be done to enable the error screen on Xcode

Attached the screenshot.
[image]
Thanks
Tejas

Comment: try to see if there are any errors in the report navigator tab.